# Bootstrap Tabs (Chrome and Firefox)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, brightcove

I have 2 tabs using Bootstrap Tabs.
Each tab has a object tag with Brightcove flash player code.

**Every time a tab is switched in Firefox the state of flash player (if video was paused) is maintained while in Chrome the video reloads.**

On each tab click, we are showing respective video player. Using templateLoadHandler we are tracking which tabs are loaded with player and on each tab switch we are pausing videos on other tabs.

This seems to work fine on Firefox and IE but on Chrome we are seeing that every time a tab is active (or brought in focus using fade in fade out) templateLoadHandler fires. So every switch of tab fires templateLoadHandler in Chrome while not in FF and IE.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var player;
    var modVP;
    var playerlist = new Array();

  function myTemplateLoaded(experienceID) {
        playerlist.push(experienceID);
        console.log(experienceID);
        player = brightcove.api.getExperience(experienceID);
        modVP = player.getModule(brightcove.api.modules.APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER);
    }


</script>


<ul id="myTab" class="nav-tabs ">

      <li class="active">Tab 1</li>
      <li class="">Tab 2</li>
  </ul>

       <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">

<div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade active in">
     <object class="BrightcoveExperience" id="myExperience0">
                            <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF">
                            <param name="width" value="700">
                            <param name="height" value="440">
                            <param name="playerID" value="XXXXXXXXX">
                            <param name="@videoPlayer" value="XXXXXXXXXXX">
                            <param name="isVid" value="true">
                            <param name="autoStart" value="false">
                            <param name="isUI" value="true">
                            <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true">
                            <param name="wmode" value="Transparent">
                            <param name="templateLoadHandler" value="myTemplateLoaded">
                            <param name="includeAPI" value="true">
                            <param name="htmlFallback" value="false">
                        </object>


</div>

<div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <object class="BrightcoveExperience" id="myExperience1">
                            <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF">
                            <param name="width" value="700">
                            <param name="height" value="440">
                            <param name="playerID" value="XXXXXXXXX">
                            <param name="@videoPlayer" value="XXXXXXXXXXX">
                            <param name="isVid" value="true">
                            <param name="autoStart" value="false">
                            <param name="isUI" value="true">
                            <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true">
                            <param name="wmode" value="Transparent">
                            <param name="templateLoadHandler" value="myTemplateLoaded">
                            <param name="includeAPI" value="true">
                            <param name="htmlFallback" value="false">
                        </object>


</div>

</div>
```

In above code: playerlist array keeps growing in Chrome while in Firefox has fixed 2 tabs.

Chrome: Console Output as myTemplateLoaded fire every time video player is loaded.

```
myExperience0
myExperience1
myExperience0
myExperience1
myExperience0
myExperience1
..... every time tab is switched. Video player reloads.
```

Firefox/IE9: Console output. myTemplateLoaded is fired only once for each player.

```
myExperience0
myExperience1
```

... only once. Previous state of video player is maintained.

Does anyone have any ideas on this?
I don't think its Brightcove API issue but something to do with either bootstrap tab with Chrome or just Chrome handling videos inside tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome does not load swfs in hidden elements until they are displayed. It unloads swfs when they are hidden, and reloads them when shown again. One way to get around that it to use `width:0;height:0;overflow:hidden` instead of `display:none` when hiding the tab.

Comment: Newer versions of Firefox now behave like Chrome in this respect. I'm not sure in which version that changed, but this is the case with Firefox 24.